# Excel VBA - Opening a Workbook that is simultaneously being saved by someone else

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that opens a workbook on a timer loop.  The workbook being opened is regularly saved by another computer elsewhere on the network. Occasionally it'll clash when it tries to open the workbook at the exact moment it's being saved and then it throws a 400 Error.

Any ideas?

```
Sub LoopDash()

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w2 = Workbooks
src = "S:\Dashboard.xlsm"
Set wb1 = w2.Open(FileName:=src, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)

alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:15")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "ThisWorkbook.LoopDash"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rick, why don't you use an "on error" statement to catch the error, and since the error only comes up at the exact moment its being saved, get the script to just wait for 5-10 seconds or however long it takes to save the file, then use the "resume" statement to resume the code and (re-)try to open the file?

Comment: I actually missed the "On Error Resume Next" code I had in the line...  It still faults out with the 400 error.

Comment: On error resume next basically tells excel to "ignore the error and carry on from where it was", which isn't useful in your particular scenario.  I would put "on error goto <linelabel>, and at the line label have a line of code that makes the program wait for 10 seconds, then resume, if that makes sense

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks.